# Solidity | Brownie: Multiple winner lottery not working

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, brownie

Github repo located here: https://github.com/supsam89/digiwear_nft_drop

The command I'm having problems with is `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`

I am trying to deploy a drop/lottery contract that picks multiple winners randomly based on entrants (then will eventually transfer an NFT to them).

When I get to end the drop/lottery function it either takes too long (gas intensive) or doesn't work. After performing `time.sleep(60)` the state remains as "Calculating winners".

The function I believe is causing the problem in NFTDrop.sol:

```
    function endDrop() public onlyOwner {
        drop_state = DROP_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNERS;
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
        emit RequestedRandomness(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness) internal override {
        require(
            drop_state == DROP_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNERS,
            "Not calculating winners yet!"
        );
        require(_randomness > 0, "randomness-not-found");
        uint256[] memory expandedValues = expand(_randomness, tokenAmount);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAmount; i++) {
            uint256 indexOfWinner = expandedValues[i] % entrants.length;
            recentWinner = entrants[indexOfWinner];
            winners.push(recentWinner);
        }
        drop_state = DROP_STATE.CLOSED;
        randomness = _randomness;
    }

    function expand(uint256 _randomness, uint256 _numberOfTokens) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
        expandedValues = new uint256[](_numberOfTokens);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _numberOfTokens; i++) {
            expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(_randomness, i)));
        }
        return expandedValues;
    }
```

Any help to the problem or advise on how to code this better would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Chainlink docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/).

> Maximum Gas for Callback
> If your fulfillRandomness function uses more than 200k gas, the transaction will fail.

Your `fulfillRandomness` function takes too much gas, you'll have to shorten it.

Comment: Got it, moved logic into endDrop instead and working. Many thanks, also for the amazing tutorial that has catapulted my progress :D